# how to use variables when setting CSS properties in Jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to get the following to work:

```
var $marPad = $('#wrapper').attr('id') == "overthrow" ? 
      ["margin-top", "margin-bottom"] : ["padding-top", "padding-bottom"];

$("#toBeSet").css({ 
    $marPad[0] : "100px", 
    $marPad[1] : "100px"
    })
```

This way I was hoping to get by with only a single css setter. However Firebug always tells me I cannot make a CSS selector like so *$marPad[0]*. It always returns **missing : after property id**.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong and if it's possible at all to also use variables instead of fixed CSS selectors?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but `$('#wrapper').attr('id') == "overthrow"` will always return false, since you are selecting an element by ID and checking if it's ID is something it's not. So `$marPad` will always equal `["padding-top", "padding-bottom"]`.

Comment: @jasper - correct. I just made this up for the question. I'm checking for a custom jqm-data attribute, which works fine. thx for pointing out though!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to first create the object, then add properties to it.

```
var obj = {}; 

obj[$marPad[0]] = '100px';
obj[$marPad[1]] = '100px';

$("#toBeSet").css(obj);
```

Perhaps better would be to make it part of the conditional statement in the first place...

```
var $marPad = $('#wrapper').attr('id') == "overthrow" ? 
      {marginTop:'100px', marginBottom: '100px'} : {paddingTop:'100px', paddingBottom:'100px'};

$("#toBeSet").css($marPad);
```

Comment: both nice. the 2nd solution only looks better. My original code is a little more complex, so I'm leaning to the first version

Answer (score 2):

The `key` part of an object literal definition is not evaluated. That is, you can't do something like this:

```
x = {
  1 + 1: 'foo'
};
```

Even though you don't always need quotes, the left-hand side is treated as a string identifier. It then follows that variables are not evaluated:

```
foo = 'bar';
x = {
  foo: 'my value'
}
x.bar === undefined;
x.foo === 'my value';
```

The only way to evaluate an expression is to use the square-bracket notation:

```
foo = 'bar';
x = {};  // an empty object
x[foo] = 'my value';    // <-- foo is evaluated, returns the string value 'bar'

x.bar === 'my value';
x.foo === undefined;

// and to clarify:
x['foo'] === undefined;
x[foo] === 'my value'
```

So, to answer your question directly, as @am not i am said, you should do something like this:

```
obj = {};
obj[$marPad[0]] = "100px"; 
obj[$marPad[1]] = "100px";
$('#toBeSet').css(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$("#toBeSet").css($marPad[0], "100px").css($marPad[1], "100px");
```

Comment: this works. Any idea how I can add more than one element into the CSS rule?

Comment: I think this skirts around the real issue in the question: why doesn't the syntax behave as expected?

Comment: I think it behaves as expected, there are some great explenation in other answers - in defining object in that way keys must be strings (can be without quotation - this differs from JSON object).

Answer (score 1):

You can't use variables as names in an object literal. Create the object and add the properties to it:

```
var o = {};
o[$marPad[0]] = "100px";
o[$marPad[1]] = "100px";

$("#toBeSet").css(o)
```

Comment: that's a neat way of doing this! Thanks!